# Unable to add theme wrapper on Woocommerce content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to integrate Woocommerce on my Wordpress website but for some reasons it is not doing the theme wrapping as needed.

Below is my code inside functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
    echo '<div class="page-details" id="shop-container">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
    echo '</div><!-- /.page-details -->';
}

add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

And I have also added `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` inside **woocommerce.php** file inside my template directory. Just like they have explained over here : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` to your template is an **alternative** step, not something you should perform in addition to the code you added to functions.php.  I recommend taking out the woocommerce_content() statement, and keeping the changes to functions.php for maximum control and clarity.